# ide for c socket programming in windows 7

Tags: c++, c, sockets, network-programming, dev-c++

I am trying to learn socket/network programming in c. I tried using dev c++ and code lite for building and compiling my C codes. I am repeatedly getting missing header files error (sys/socket.h, sys/param.h etc.). When ever I download the missing files and place them in the directories, it keep on getting some files cannot be located error. I am really fed up. Kindly suggest me a good c compiler in which all libraries needed for the network programmings are included and which will not give me headache asking me to download the missing header files. Or is there anyway to download the complete library files required for compiling the socket programs in C using dev c++ or codelight??

Comment: Libraries and headers are not included in a compiler. Furthermore, compiler != IDE != libraries.

Comment: Dev-c++ was already outdated when I started using it and that's quite some years ago. Personally I am using Visual Studio for bigger projects (Compiles native C just fine if you change some things) or most of times just notepad++ with GCC
(Code::Blocks isn't that bad either and it's free)

Comment: I'd start with the [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138), which includes Microsoft's C-compiler. Or perhaps [Visual C++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products). Looking for opinion on "Whats a good/best...--**anything**-..." is one of the fastest ways to get a question closed as non-constructive, so don't be alarmed if that happens.

Comment: I don't understand why some people here are readily awarding negative votes. I know this kind of questions may be disgusting to some of you, but I've got no other choice. I've no other place to get answer for this question. Even though it may appear silly to you people, its really important one for me, as I am learning all these stuffs alone for doing my course project. Kindly help me!

Answer (score 0):

BSD Sockets are on Linux. On Windows, there is winsock - and is bundled with MinGW.

You've tagged your question as C++ - in C++ there is Boost.Asio for socket programming.

And, for the record, please don't use Dev-C++ version 4.9.9.2. It's very old (2005). Use Code::Blocks or Orwell Dev-C++ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just install Visual Studio C++ Express and it would be a good idea to spend one or two days to get out the basics of how code generation works! ;-)

Comment: sir, but i ve heard that for a real time network monitoring and analysis c will be better as .net is massive and it will miss a lot of packets. Is there any way to do programming in c alone, without .net interference?

Comment: @Ganesh Visual Studio C++ is not connected to .NET whatsoever.

Comment: so can I use visual c++ for building an Intruder detection system, and will it be fast enough to catch all the packets without much problem?

Comment: I don't know anybody who uses the possibility to programm c++ with .net :-)

Comment: What do mean with "intruder detection system"?